# Display 3D buildings on map

Tags: api, 3d, maps, webgl, openstreetmap

Can someone show me a working example of 3D visualization of buildings on map, with GPS coordinates and building dimensions used as an input information. Plain 3D box wire frame display would be enough. Additionally, different buildings suppose to be presented with different colors, and clicking one of them should open a popup with photo and other information.

Answer (score 1):

[OSMBuildings](https://osmbuildings.org/) is a mature choice for buildings based on OpenStreetMap data. See the [OpenStreetMap 3D wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D) for alternative options along those lines.

If you serve your own building data, another popular candidate is the [Cesium.js](https://cesiumjs.org/) library. They have a [demo](https://demos.cesium.com/NewYork/) which checks all your boxes, including the ability to colour buildings by particular attributes and to pop up attributes by clicking them.